# Dealing with collections in MVEL

Tags: java, mvel

I have the following field:

```
List<Map<String, Long>> vehicles;
```

where each map contains 2 pairs:

```
"id" -> N
"order" -> M
```

How can I find a map by `id` and extract the corresponsing `order` in MVEL?

In Java it looks like:

```
vehicles.stream().find(m -> m.get("id") == N).findAny().map(m -> m.get("order")).orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out one can iterate over list of maps, filter them and extract value in the following way:

```
order: Number() from accumulate(
 Map(this["id"] == N, $ord: this["order"]) from vehicles, max($ord)
)
```